# How to apply ProgressBarStyle?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, android-progressbar

I'm trying to apply a theme to all of the progress bars in my application. In the manifest, I apply a custom theme called `AppTheme`. Within this style, I add an additional `progressBarStyle` item like so:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/my_progress_bar</item>
</style>
```

And I define the custom bar progress style as such:

```
<style name="my_progress_bar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">@color/app_black</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_in</item>
</style>
```

If I apply this style to individual ProgressBar views, it works, but I want to apply it in my manifest through the AppTheme so that I don't have to specify the same tint and tintMode for every progress bar across the app. I am using a device running API 25.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any insight.

Edit: after further investigation, for some reason adding the style to the AppTheme doesn't propagate through to the manifest. If I replace the AppTheme with my progress bar style entirely, it works. But I still need the styles defined in `AppTheme`.
this works: 
    `<application ...
        android:theme="@style/my_progress_bar">`

but this does not:
    `<application ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

What's interesting is that if I remove everything in AppTheme except for the progress bar styling I define, it doesn't work. Is there a bug with nested styles in android? My manifest doesn't see the progressBarStyle defined when I just pass it this AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/my_progress_bar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **manifest file**, you have the following:

```
<application
        android:name="app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

.......
</application>
```

add the following to your AppTheme within your **style.xml** file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--This will change the color of your progress bar throughout the whole app-->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/app_black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: unfortunately, `colorControlActivated` item does fix the issue for me

Comment: does or does not?

Comment: apologies, I mean't does not